# Filter grep result-set by paths containing folder1/folder2 and trim the current folder path from result-set

Tags: linux, grep, terminal, path, filter

I have a `grep` command like below to search for all `.xml` files containing given string.

```
grep -rl 'product_list_toolbar_pager' --include='*.xml' --color=always
```

Now I am using this command on remote SSH terminal, where I am already inside the `/home/user/public_html/` directory path, so from the result set of the above command, how can I trim the starting folders upto which I am already inside. Means if I run the above command inside `/home/user` then it should return result set containing paths starting from `public_html/` but if I run the same from inside `/home/user/public_html/` then it should return the paths starting from directory after `public_html/`.

Now about my second need, I want to filter the result set of the above command to only contain paths which have `folder1/folder2` in their path heirarchy.

How can I acheive both these needs with minumum code as possible in SSH terminal ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your first query, do you want to include **all** the directory including `public_html/` if the commande is ran in `/home/user`, or only the `public_html/` directory?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I need paths "starting from" the `public_html/` if I am inside `/home/user/` and I need paths starting after(containing all the rest of the subfolders along the found path) `public_html/` if I am inside `home/user/public_html/`.